# Mocking with rspec and mocha together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing, mocha.js

For a test suite that's already using mocha for mocking, can new tests be written with rspec mocking? maybe turn that on before(:all) and turn it back to mocha after(:all)

I tried changing the Spec::Runner configuration at run-time and that didn't seem to work with mocking

Comment: I'd rephrase your question "rspec mocking seems to conflict with mocha. how do I use both in a project?", and perhaps direct it at the rspec people in IRC, github issues, etc.

Comment: Please specify what version of rspec you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have published a new gem for this. You can find more details here -> http://github.com/endeepak/rspec-multi-mock

Comment: thanks a million for this :) Using it right now to migrate from Mocha to RSpec.

Comment: I'm glad it is serving the purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Deepak's [RSpec Multi Mock](http://github.com/endeepak/rspec-multi-mock) gem solves this.

But you should ask yourself if this is really what you want. Ultimately, consistency is most important, and using a mix of mocking frameworks within the same app is bound to lead to confusion.

Personally I'm quite happy with RSpec's built-in mocking and don't usually find the need for Mocha on my own projects. But some of my peers prefer Mocha and I'm not really aware of any limitations of Mocha compared to vanilla RSpec mocking, so I'd recommend sticking with Mocha if that's what the app already uses. Even though I know its "any_instance" support is considered a code smell by some, it does occasionally come in very handy. :)

Comment: I totally agree with you. As i have mentioned on the github page, this gem should probably be used while one is switching from one framework to another and you don't have enough time to convert all usages.Or when some thing you need is not available in the current mocking framework. Or there are cases where you merge two projects and they use different mocking frameworks.
The end goal should be to use single framework and avoid confusions